# Accessing Map Interface Object created in Main class

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Consider the following two classes :

**Class A** begins here is a separate java file in the same package:

```
public class A {

public void putIntoMap(int a[]){
  Map <Integer, Integer> intMapObject = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++){

          // some code here
       }
       intMapObject.put(a[i], count);
}


}
```

**Class B** begins here is a separate java file in the same package:

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    A a = new A();

    a.putIntoMap(arr); // assume arr is an array I already have

    // Now I need to do loop over the Map and I need the `intMapObject`  //object from above class A


// I need to do something like this 

for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e : intMapObject.entrySet()){


  // some code here

     }

}
```

How do I access `intMapObject` object in class B ?

Comment: You don't. It's local to the method and you haven't exposed it as a return value or in any other way.

Comment: I did not notice that `intMapObject` is in method. In that case it should be returned from the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access variables declared in another method. Ever.

But that doesn't mean you can't pass objects from one method to another. In this case, I suggest making `putIntoMap` return the new map:

```
// in A
public Map<Integer, Integer> putIntoMap(int a[]){
  Map <Integer, Integer> intMapObject = // ...
  // some code to put the stuff in the map here

  return intMapObject;
}

// in B
A a = new A();
Map<Integer, Integer> theMap = a.putIntoMap(arr);
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : theMap.entrySet()) {
    // some code here
}
```

Note that this does not pass the actual object, but a reference to it. In Java, objects are not stored in variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I learnt something new here although I have seen such type of code many times before.